# How to read NFC type A card pages?

Tags: android, nfc

I have an Android app that is reading Mifare Ultralight card content. Previously all cards had Ultralight in `android.nfc.tech` and I was using `readPages()` to get the data with no problems.

Now I encountered new types of card that do not have Ultralight in `android.nfc.tech` and I can't use `readPages()` anymore. However I encounter that TagInfo app by NXP does read pages. How can I achieve same result? Should I use `tranceive()` command? What command should I generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [MifareUltralight](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/tech/MifareUltralight.java) source and try to reproduce code for your tag:

```
public byte[] readPages(int pageOffset) throws IOException {
    validatePageIndex(pageOffset);
    checkConnected();
    byte[] cmd = { 0x30, (byte) pageOffset};
    return transceive(cmd, false);
}
```

Comment: @MaratK, is it useful ?

Comment: Yes, it did work! I was trying to implement this before with no luck, after your suggestion I tried to try it again. Probably I used wrong data type as pageOffset parameter before.